# Using formik validation and submit ckeditor and file input in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, formik

I want to validate my inputs and also submit them in my project. I have a file input and also a ckeditor and some other text input required fields. When the file is uploaded, the logoAddress is received by my react app. First of all I want to know how is better I validate it and then how to use formik validation for other inputs. My code is like bellow but there are some problems. For example because of using `enableReinitialize={true}`, it resets the initial values to the empty string and it returns error messages for text inputs unless I fill them after ckeditor and file inputs. I am new to react and using ckeditor in it. Because I want to use it in a way to be able to use in another component to Update those fields, I prefer to have a solution to be applicable for editing them too.

```
 return (
        <>
            <section className="p-3">
                <img
                    src={require("../../assets/company5.png")}
                    height="400px"
                    style={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        zIndex: "-1",
                        top: "130px",
                        opacity: "50%",
                        ...absolutePosition
                    }}
                />
                <div className="container">

                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <p
                                className="h4 fw-bold"
                                style={{ color: GREEN }}
                            >
                                {t('Create Company')}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr style={{ backgroundColor: GREEN }} />
                    <div className="row mt-5">
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <Formik
                                initialValues={{
                                    name: '',
                                    establishmentYear: '',
                                    personnels: '',
                                    about: aboutCompany,
                                    logo: logoAddress
                                }}

                                enableReinitialize={true}
                                validationSchema={companySchema}
                                onSubmit={(values) => {
                                    console.log(values);
                                    submitForm(values);
                                }}
                            >
                                <Form>
                                    <div className="mb-2">

                                        {
                                            !loadingImage ? logoAddress &&
                                                <img src={logoAddress} alt="company-logo" className="img-thumbnail m-2" style={{ width: '50px', height: '50px' }}></img>
                                                : <Spinner />
                                        }
                                        <input
                                            type="file"
                                            className="form-control d-inline"
                                            onInput={(e) => uploadLogo(e)}
                                            name="logo"
                                        />
                                        <ErrorMessage name='logo' render={msg => <div style={errorColorStyle}>{t(msg)}</div>} />

                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mb-2">
                                        <Field
                                        
                                            value={companyName}
                                            name="name"
                                            type="text"
                                            className="form-control"
                                            placeholder={t('Company Name')}
                                        />
                                        <ErrorMessage name='name' render={msg => <div style={errorColorStyle}>{t(msg)}</div>} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mb-2">
                                        <Field
                                    
                                            type='number'
                                            value={stablishedYear}
                                            placeholder={t('Establishment Year')}
                                            name="establishmentYear"
                                            className='form-control' />
                                        <ErrorMessage name='establishmentYear' render={msg => <div style={errorColorStyle}>{t(msg)}</div>} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mb-2">
                                        <Field
                                
                                            type='number'
                                            value={personCount}
                                            name="personnels"
                                            placeholder={t('Number of Employees')}
                                            className='form-control' />
                                        <ErrorMessage name='personnels' render={msg => <div style={errorColorStyle}>{t(msg)}</div>} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mb-2">
                                        <h2>Using CKEditor&nbsp;5 build in React</h2>
                                        <CKEditor
                                            editor={ClassicEditor}
                                            data="<p>Hello from CKEditor&nbsp;5!</p>"
                                            onReady={editor => {
                                                // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                                                console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
                                            }}
                                            onChange={(event, editor) => {
                                                setAboutCompany(editor.getData());
                                            }}
                                            onBlur={(event, editor) => {
                                                console.log('Blur.', editor);
                                            }}
                                            onFocus={(event, editor) => {
                                                console.log('Focus.', editor);
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <ErrorMessage name='about' render={msg => <div style={errorColorStyle}>{t(msg)}</div>} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mx-2">
                                        <button
                                            type="submit"
                                            className="btn"
                                            style={{ backgroundColor: PURPLE }}>
                                            {t('register company')}
                                        </button>
                                        <Link
                                            to={"/employer/jobs"}
                                            className="btn mx-2"
                                            style={{ backgroundColor: COMMENT }}
                                        >
                                            {t('cancel')}
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                </Form>
                            </Formik>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section >
        </>
    );
```